# How to print max() value in JSON

Tags: php, laravel

How can I print highest value in `JSON` form result of 3 functions.

Controller :

```
 class TimeFrameStatisticsController extends Controller

{
        public function one()
        {
            return 3;
        }
        public function two()
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public function three()
        {
            return 4;
        }

        //FUNCTION FOR 4rth to get HIGHEST value

        public function HighestValue() {

            $func_names = ['three','one','two'];

            // Call each method and store result.
            foreach($func_names as $name) {
                $results[$name] = $name();
            }

            $max       = max($results);
            $max_funcs = array_keys($results, $max);

            return response()->json($max_funcs);
           }
}
```

> Error in OUTPUT of `public function HighestValue()` for API : **Call
>   to undefined function** `public function one()`

AND

Other 3 functions are result by API:

[image]

My Question is what should i do? Should I create Object and how ?

Comment: Firstly, to call those methods: `$results[$name] = $this->$name();`.

Comment: Note here that max_funcs may have more than one value (method names).  If we have more than one same max value.

Comment: can you do it for me? I dont know actually how to call method? ` $results[$one] = $this->$one();  ` Should i do this? @Progrock

Comment: Step back and think about this.  If $name holds the value 'one'.  Then when you call like this $this->$name() it translates to $this->one(), get it?

Comment: (Being able to call a method is Php Oop 101.)

Comment: Let me tell you clear, I am watching video and learn. I am not actual developer but i want to learn. I am confused because there're 3 function and i am trying to find which one is max via API...  I understand for-each condition . But brain in stuck. @Progrock

Comment: $results[$one] = $one(); $results[$two] = $two(); $results[$three] = $three(); @Progrock

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172837/discussion-between-kinnari-prajapati-and-progrock).

Comment: You are fundamentally not understanding the foreach and variable assignment.  Try running some code.  `foreach (['alice','bob'] as $name) { echo $name; }` would display `alicebob`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. result would be `alicebob`. but also possible `bob`. @Progrock  `$results[$func_names] = $name();`

Comment: This has turned into complete nonsense.  I'm out of here.

Comment: I have solved it by my self from you conversation ... let me inform you that, you did not wasted your time behind me.. I learn one thing when same class i can call function via $this .  and i have done it.. it giving me result @Progrock

Comment: Glad you figured it out, that's great.  Apologies for my frustration.

Comment: You are my mentor, Mention can be angry. Thank again for guiding me. I have also posted answer here what i have done and its giving me perfect result. You can teach me or guide if you wish. @Progrock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function giving me perfect result of highest value from 3 different.

```
public function allCmp()
{

    $firstTradeValue = $this->one();
    $lastTradeValue = $this->two();
    $otherTradeValue = $this->three();

//Set all in one array
    $allTrades = array("firstHourTrades" => $firstTradeValue, "lastHourTrades" => $lastTradeValue, "otherHoursTrades" => $otherTradeValue );

//Get the highest value
    $highestValue = max($allTrades);

//Get the corresponding key
    $key = array_search($highestValue, $allTrades);


    return response()->json($key);

}
```